# Javascript won't find my div

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML file with a div and a javascript file that uses this div as a variable in a function like so:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

And the JS

```
foo = document.getElementById("foo");
function bar() {
  foo.innerHTML = "foobar"
}
```

But when I run `bar` (after load, in console) it says that `bar` is undefined and does not change `foo.innerHTML` to `"foobar"`

**UPDATE**: I call `bar()` in the console after the page is loaded. I also fixed the code up there

Comment: You need to ensure the document is loaded by the time your script runs with window.onload. And you are missing a () in function bar(){//code}

Comment: Why the down-votes? Seems like a perfectly good enough question to me.

Comment: Also you're missing a semi-colon on `foo.innerHTML = "foobar"`. Not necessary, but good for practice.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel - semi-colons are optional

Comment: @j08691 thanks, clarified my comment.

Comment: Sorry for editing mistake in actuall code there is ()

Comment: So, `bar` is undefined?  Not `foo`?  Where is `bar` being defined?  It sounds like it's being defined inside another function and therefore only exists in that scope (not the global scope).

Comment: `bar` was defined right there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your script to

```
function bar() {
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "foobar"
}
```

There is a problem with your script. The way you are declaring your function is syntactically incorrect.

Additionally, you should make sure that when you are calling your function, the element exists in DOM.

Errors can be spotted by opening Developer Tools (F12 > Console) and fixing the respective errors

Also make sure you have your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag in order to let JS parse the document before mapping the needed elements into DOM

Comment: We don't know how/when he's calling `bar()`.  There's nothing wrong with doing `document.getElementById("foo")` outside of the function, assuming that's ran *after* the page is fully loaded.  For all we know, `bar()` could be being called before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I agree. I am in process of updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you invoked the script before the element was loaded.

You can either use jQuery

```
$(function() { /* Code goes here */ }
```

or vanilla JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() { /* Code goes here */ }
```

to fix this.

Comment: I updated your answer to say "vanilla JavaScript".  jQuery *is* JavaScript, so I added "vanilla" to clarify that you meant "without an additional library".

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the document is loaded by the time your script runs with window.onload. And you are missing a () in your bar function:

```
window.onload = function(){ // we wait for the document to load
    var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); // now we are sure the div exists
    function bar() { // note the missing ()
        document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "foobar"
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing a semicolon after document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "foobar"

Comment: @psylogic - semi-colons are optional, unless you are working on strict mode which doesn´t seem the case here. But its good practice to add it